# Reference request for widely used theorem

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, hurwitz-theory

I am looking for a reference to the theorem that any oriented closed surface of genus $g$ is a 2-fold cover of $S^2$ (branched over 2$g$+2  points).

Answer (score 1):

Proposition 1.2.2 has a nice figure associated to it.

https://www.danielezuddas.eu/pdf/tesi.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 4 in the paper "[Branched polynomial covering maps](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864101002590)" by Vagn Lundsgaard Hansen (Topology and its Applications **125**(2002) 63-72).